# Null Pointer Exception in Response using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am again trying to use TMBD api. I am using a recyclerview to map the data into a list.But the response I am getting from the retrofit response is null.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String BASE_URL="https://api.themoviedb.org";
    public final static String apiKey="<ApiKey>";
    public final static String language="en-US";
    public final static String TAG="tag";

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView movieList;

    DisplayAdapter adapter;
    MovieResponse result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                .build();

        ApiInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        apiInterface.getMovies(apiKey,language,1)
                .enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            result=response.body();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+result );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) { }
                });

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+result );
        adapter=new DisplayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),result);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),1);
        movieList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        movieList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Response Class:

```
public class MovieResponse {

    private int page;
    private int total_results;
    private int total_pages;
    private List<ResultsBean> results;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getTotal_results() {
        return total_results;
    }

    public void setTotal_results(int total_results) {
        this.total_results = total_results;
    }

    public int getTotal_pages() {
        return total_pages;
    }

    public void setTotal_pages(int total_pages) {
        this.total_pages = total_pages;
    }

    public List<ResultsBean> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<ResultsBean> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public static class ResultsBean {

        private double popularity;
        private int vote_count;
        private boolean video;
        private String poster_path;
        private int id;
        private boolean adult;
        private String backdrop_path;
        private String original_language;
        private String original_title;
        private String title;
        private double vote_average;
        private String overview;
        private String release_date;
        private List<Integer> genre_ids;

        public double getPopularity() {
            return popularity;
        }

        public void setPopularity(double popularity) {
            this.popularity = popularity;
        }

        public int getVote_count() {
            return vote_count;
        }

        public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
            this.vote_count = vote_count;
        }

        public boolean isVideo() {
            return video;
        }

        public void setVideo(boolean video) {
            this.video = video;
        }

        public String getPoster_path() {
            return poster_path;
        }

        public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
            this.poster_path = poster_path;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public boolean isAdult() {
            return adult;
        }

        public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
            this.adult = adult;
        }

        public String getBackdrop_path() {
            return backdrop_path;
        }

        public void setBackdrop_path(String backdrop_path) {
            this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
        }

        public String getOriginal_language() {
            return original_language;
        }

        public void setOriginal_language(String original_language) {
            this.original_language = original_language;
        }

        public String getOriginal_title() {
            return original_title;
        }

        public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
            this.original_title = original_title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public double getVote_average() {
            return vote_average;
        }

        public void setVote_average(double vote_average) {
            this.vote_average = vote_average;
        }

        public String getOverview() {
            return overview;
        }

        public void setOverview(String overview) {
            this.overview = overview;
        }

        public String getRelease_date() {
            return release_date;
        }

        public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
            this.release_date = release_date;
        }

        public List<Integer> getGenre_ids() {
            return genre_ids;
        }

        public void setGenre_ids(List<Integer> genre_ids) {
            this.genre_ids = genre_ids;
        }
    }
}
```

The Api Interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("3/movie/popular")
    Call<MovieResponse> getMovies(
            @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
            @Query("language")String language,
            @Query("page")int page
    );
}
```

I am learning the concept of api calling. I dont understand why the response is null. If anybody could explai the reason it will be very helpfull.

Comment: Is your apiKey correct?

Comment: hit the API via Postman and verify the API structure match with your POJO class 'MovieResponse'

Comment: Yes the api key is correct. I tried it woth postman as well. I matches with my POJO class as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be several things from what you posted.

It can be that the Java models don't match the JSON. You'd have to double check this.

It can be that you're getting an error, in which case retrofit does not have a `response.body()`, but rather a `response.errorBody()`. You can check this by debugging and checking `response.erroeBody().string()`.

Or it could to be a classic example of asynch behaviour being handled like it's synchronous.

```
adapter=new DisplayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),result);
```

In this case you're using `result`, but it's assigned inside the retrofit callback which most likely finished after you create the adapter and hence `result` is still null.

You can move the creation of the adapter and setting it to the list inside the callback:

```
public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        result=response.body();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+result );

                       adapter=new DisplayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),result);
                       RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),1);
                       movieList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                       movieList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
```

These are the only things that come to mind. Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT**

After taking a look at the github project, the only thing I found that is crashing the app is inside `DisplayAdapter.java` line 44:

```
holder.movieRating.setText((int) listOfMovies.getResults().get(position).getVote_average());
```

When you call `setText` that accepts an `int` you are in fact calling a method that will look in your `strings.xml` for a string with the id equal to the `int` you passed in. In this case, you are passing the vote average as an `int`. I'm guessing that what you want is to display the vote average, so the solution is to convert the `double` vote average to a string. This can easily be achieved with `String.valueOf`:

```
holder.movieRating.setText(String.valueOf(listOfMovies.getResults().get(position).getVote_average()));
```

Perhaps the most interesting bit is in the log message `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7`. This is thrown when trying to look for the string that doesn't exist.

Comment: I am still not getting the result on the screen

Comment: There are a lot of things that can be wrong here. From the call failing to the adapter not correctly set up. If you want you can leave a link to the project so we can have a look.

Comment: https://github.com/krnsree/Movino . This is the link of the project

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know what I find